# Импорт базы данных в docker, лучший вариант

Tags: docker, dump

Какой лучший вариант для синхронизации базы данных между контейнером и локальным компьютером? Как пробросить дамп и как получать изменения на выходе, чтобы после следующего запуска контейнера всегда получать свежую версию той базы данных с которой закончил работу?

Comment: Хранить данные в volume, наверное?

Comment: если, базы не работают одновременно volume или общая папка, если работают - репликация

Comment: @ExplodingKitten общая папка это bind на файловую систему? Так не работает, она не открывает таблицу после создания контейнера так как она не была создана конкретно в этой базу, не помню уже что за ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разработчиками на этот случай была предусмотрена специальная папка внутри образа mariaDB (как и MySQL, Postgress и тд) по пути `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Любые *.sql или *.sh файлы в этом каталоге будут рассматриваться как скрипты для инициализации БД.

То есть в моем случае в docker-compose для mariadb был указан следующий volume:

```
volumes:
    - ./mariadb/database/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

В `/mariadb/database/` лежит база данных. При кадом запуске контейнера она будет создаваться внутри него, и делать это очень быстро. Это довольно удобно.

Например, вы запустили свои контейнера для локальной разработки. Затем вы выполнили команду `UPDATE your_table SET name = 'Ivan'`, но забыли указать `WHERE + предикат`. Если вы использовали локальную среду для разработки, такую как OpenServer, то вам придется снести базу и установить новую. Используя докер можно вызвать две команды `docker-compose down` и `docker-compose up` и он опять запустит существующие у вас контейнера и заново сделает импорт той базы данных, которую вы привязали (volume). В общем очень удобно.